# Why ContourPlot is not working with functions

Tags: plotting

I have the following code that I don't know how to fix:

```
g = x^2 + 4 y^2 - z^2
ContourPlot[g == 0 /. z -> 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

The function `g == 0 /. z -> 1` evaluates alright to `-1 + x^2 + 4 y^2 == 0`, but for some reason the contour plot is not recognizing it. Any quick fix?

Comment: Wrap the expression in ``Evaluate``: ``ContourPlot[Evaluate[g == 0 /. z -> 1], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found issues of evaluation order one of my commonest problems in learning Mathematica.  As @Domen suggested, you can evaluate the expression to force the substitution of `z`

```
g = x^2 + 4 y^2 - z^2;
ContourPlot[Evaluate[g == 0 /. z -> 1], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

As an alternative, you can substitute a local value for `z` using `Block`

```
Block[{z = 1}, ContourPlot[g == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the core issue is that `ContourPlot` can't see the `==` and is thus assuming that you're trying to do a "standard" contour plot (rather than e.g. something related directly to the evaluation order of `g` and the replacement of `z`)